# How to pass unicode values as urlfetch payload?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, unicode

Here is the simplified code I have:

```
#coding=utf-8
...

def api_call(method, token, params=[], payload=None):
    ...
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
    try:
        response = urlfetch.Fetch(url, headers=headers, method=urlfetch.POST, payload=payload, deadline=60)
    ...

payload = '{"search":"%s"}' % ('тест') # UNICODE HERE!

result = api_call(method=method, token=MY_TOKEN, payload=payload)
```

This code works well with non-unicode characters, but when unicode is used, I get:

```
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Dev/GAE/app.py", line 38, in api_call
    response = urlfetch.Fetch(url, headers=headers, method=urlfetch.POST, payload=payload, deadline=60)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 271, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 378, in _get_fetch_result
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 579, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 219, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    request_pb.set_request(request.Encode())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 103, in Encode
    self.Output(e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 347, in Output
    self.OutputUnchecked(e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_service_pb.py", line 478, in OutputUnchecked
    out.putPrefixedString(self.payload_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 607, in putPrefixedString
    v = str(v)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 92-93: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You can't send Unicode text over a network connection without encoding it. Encode it explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. If I do `urllib.quote( u'тест'.encode('utf-8') )`, then I get no exception, but 3rd party server doesn't understand url-encoded text passed.

Comment: That may well be, but trying to send Unicode text without encoding is not the solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if I send the same data (without url-encoding) with Advanced Rest Client (Chrome addon), then it works well. Not sure how to debug what ARC sends - does it encode data or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> payload = '{"search":"%s"}' % ('тест') # UNICODE HERE!

This isn't a good way to create a JSON serialised object. Apart from the character encoding problem, you've also got issues if the templated string contains characters special in string literals, like quotes or backslashes. Suggest using the `json` module to create the serialised form and take care of encoding at the same time:

```
search = u'тест'
payload = json.dumps({'search': search})
```

> 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

There is no `charset` parameter for the `application/json` media type; this does nothing. JSON is always UTF, and by default UTF-8, anyway.